# Does the Facebook REST API allow you to get a friend's phone number?

Tags: facebook

Using the Facebook API, is there a way of getting a friend's phone/cell number? I'm sure I saw an app a while ago that could sync Facebook with your Mac Address Book, but I haven't found anything in the API documentation that allows you to get a friend's number. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FQL documentation, no.  The [User table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User_%28FQL%29) and [Standard user info table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Standard_user_info_%28FQL%29) would be the storage place for that information, but no phone number column is listed.  Also, [Users.getInfo()](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getInfo) and [Users.getStandardInfo()](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getStandardInfo) do not evidently include phone number information either.

Perhaps the app you saw strictly managed email and physical mailing addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Yes above answre is right i have properly search to find the Friend phone numbers with Graph API with PHP SDK 3.1.1 but fail because the facebook do not provide any phone number and email of the Friends but other information can get get easily via code.